Remove itemtype entries older than 90 days using an impex or cronjob
I currently have the below impex to remove all entries for an item type but I want to amend it to only remove entries older than 90 days.
Alternatively, I would like to create a cronjob to clear the entries daily which are older than 90 days.
$targetType=myItemType
REMOVE $targetType[batchmode=true];itemtype(code) [unique=true];$targetType
